# mysqli not found when called inside a class

Tags: php, mysqli, fatal-error

If I call

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName);
```

outside of a class, this works fine and I can access my database.

In another file I have created a DB.class.php.  When I call the same code but now I am inside a namespace and a class, I get this error.

> Fatal error: Class 'net[domain]\helpdesk\mysqli' not found in [path]\helpdesk\NS\helpdesk\DB.class.php on line 18

I do not understand why mysqli is not found while inside a class.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Post the class - we can't comment from what you have here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$mysqli = new \mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName);
```

That should get PHP to look in the global namespace for the class.

Comment: Thank you, I am coming from a C# and Java environment where the OOP is more fluid.  This worked like a charm.